# php xml get a value from a xml over http and then store it as a string

Tags: php, xml, string, select

Okay i really have some issues with this XML / php script

I have the following xml which i want to load over http

```
<WowzaMediaServer>
<ConnectionsCurrent>3</ConnectionsCurrent>
<ConnectionsTotal>26</ConnectionsTotal>
<ConnectionsTotalAccepted>20</ConnectionsTotalAccepted>
<ConnectionsTotalRejected>6</ConnectionsTotalRejected>
<MessagesInBytesRate>3248.0</MessagesInBytesRate>
<MessagesOutBytesRate>1054.0</MessagesOutBytesRate>
<VHost>
<Name>_defaultVHost_</Name>
<TimeRunning>28752.989</TimeRunning>
<ConnectionsLimit>0</ConnectionsLimit>
<ConnectionsCurrent>3</ConnectionsCurrent>
<ConnectionsTotal>26</ConnectionsTotal>
<ConnectionsTotalAccepted>20</ConnectionsTotalAccepted>
<ConnectionsTotalRejected>6</ConnectionsTotalRejected>
<MessagesInBytesRate>3248.0</MessagesInBytesRate>
<MessagesOutBytesRate>1054.0</MessagesOutBytesRate>
<Application>
<Name>zahlio</Name>
<Status>loaded</Status>
<TimeRunning>3339.479</TimeRunning>
<ConnectionsCurrent>3</ConnectionsCurrent>
<ConnectionsTotal>14</ConnectionsTotal>
<ConnectionsTotalAccepted>14</ConnectionsTotalAccepted>
<ConnectionsTotalRejected>0</ConnectionsTotalRejected>
<MessagesInBytesRate>31595.0</MessagesInBytesRate>
<MessagesOutBytesRate>32045.0</MessagesOutBytesRate>
<ApplicationInstance>
<Name>_definst_</Name>
<TimeRunning>3339.478</TimeRunning>
<ConnectionsCurrent>3</ConnectionsCurrent>
<ConnectionsTotal>14</ConnectionsTotal>
<ConnectionsTotalAccepted>14</ConnectionsTotalAccepted>
<ConnectionsTotalRejected>0</ConnectionsTotalRejected>
<MessagesInBytesRate>31594.0</MessagesInBytesRate>
<MessagesOutBytesRate>32045.0</MessagesOutBytesRate>
<Stream>
<Name>zahlio</Name>
<SessionsFlash>2</SessionsFlash>
<SessionsCupertino>0</SessionsCupertino>
<SessionsSanJose>0</SessionsSanJose>
<SessionsSmooth>0</SessionsSmooth>
<SessionsRTSP>0</SessionsRTSP>
<SessionsTotal>2</SessionsTotal>
</Stream>
</ApplicationInstance>
</Application>
</VHost>
</WowzaMediaServer>
```

The data i want to load is the `<SessionsFlash>` the `2` from the `<stream>` with x as name and x being a variable, in this case it zahlio.

i load it by using this http: http://username:pwd@mydomian.com:8086/connectioncounts

and this is my current php script:

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement('http://username:pwd@mydomian.com:8086/connectioncounts');
    $propNode = $sxe->xpath('/WowzaMediaServer/VHost/Application/ApplicationInstance/Stream');
    $count = $propNode->getChildren("SessionsFlash");
```

it dosnt work and i dont know how to select trh data from the child with the name x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to extract the data from the XML you posted. The following code gets the `Name` and `SessionsFlash` from provided XML:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$search_name = 'zahlio';
$items = $xpath->query('/WowzaMediaServer/VHost/Application[Name="' . $search_name . '"]/ApplicationInstance/Stream[Name="' . $search_name . '"]');
for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
{
    $temp = $xpath->query('SessionsFlash', $items->item($i));
    $SessionsFlash = $temp->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $SessionsFlash;
}
```

Your server was using [Digest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) authentication, your browser handles it automatically and PHP needs some help. Here's the code that works:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://user:pwd@website.net:8086/connectioncounts');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: i dont wanmt the name, i want the streamflash from where the <Application> name=x and <Stream> name =x

Comment: Why can't you just query for `SessionsFlash` and be done? There's one instance of it in the XML.

Comment: no because there is going to be multiple :) or else it was easy :)

Comment: tried this:

`$viewers_temp = $xml->xpath('/WowzaMediaServer/VHost/Application[Name="$channel_id"]/ApplicationInstance/Stream/[Name="$channel_id"]');
$viewers_test = $viewers_temp->item(0)->nodeValue;`

but dosnt seem to work..

Comment: Well that's something you should have specified in the question... Updated answer with working code. Check it out.

Comment: oh sorry. how would i load the xml from the http? like: `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('http://xx:xx@xxx.net:8086/connectioncounts');` ?

Comment: btw there is a sort in the <Application> too, it also needs to be thje one <Name> = something lets just say zahlio :) like i tired in my ither examble.

Comment: `$xml = file_get_contents($url);` and then `@$dom->loadXML($xml);`. Yea missed that, updated post

Comment: i cant seem to get it to work... hjere is my current code:

`$url = "http://xx:xx@xx:8086/connectioncounts";
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$search_name = 'zahlio';
$items = $xpath->query('/WowzaMediaServer/VHost/Application[Name="' . $channel_id . '"]/ApplicationInstance/Stream[Name="' . $channel_id . '"]');
for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
{
    $temp = $xpath->query('SessionsFlash', $items->item($i));
    $SessionsFlash = $temp->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $SessionsFlash;
}`

What am i missing=?

Comment: You have `$channel_id` instead of `$search_name`. Also, check `$xml` contents to see if the XML is being grabbed properly.

Comment: well the $channel_id is my search name and it is defined. how would i check that the xml is correctly grabbed?

if i go to the ` http://xx:xx@xxx.net:8086/connectioncounts ` i see the xml

Comment: well you can echo $xml and see what's being output :) You can also see if it contains something to match your channel_id. I've tested the code I posted on codepad on xml you provided and it works

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: xml in C:\xampp\htdocs\user\zahlio\index.php on line 174`....

So how do i grab the xml over http then...

Comment: If you have this line `$xml = file_get_contents($url);` then `$xml` can't be undefined. You either echo it in the wrong place or dont have that line

Comment: i have: `$url = "http://live:live@xxx.net:8086/connectioncounts";
$xml = file_get_contents($url);`

and that is what gives me that error. how to i grab the xml over http? i thkn the issue is that its not loaded.

Comment: The *is* the way you grab it. Are you sure there's no authentication required to grab the data? Move these lines into the separate script, add `var_dump($xml);` after and try it out to find out why it doesn't grab anything. I can't figure it out, since you don't post url.

Comment: Updated post with info about grabing the `$xml`

Comment: thx it works great

btw can someone edit the url i posted earlier as i odnt whant it here :)

Comment: You should be able to delete your own comment. Or get 15 reputation so you can flag for moderator attention and ask them nicely to do it for you :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I build script for Wowza Media Server too. This is how I read XML in php, maybe it can help

```
        $dom=new DOMDocument;
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $dom->load('/home/vichea/wowza_visitor/wowza_serverinfo.xml');
        $date=date("d/m/Y");
        $date_file=date('mY');

        $dataset0=$dom->getElementsByTagName("VHost");
        foreach($dataset0 as $row){
            $xmlC=$row->getElementsByTagName("ConnectionsTotal");
            $xmlConn=$xmlC->item(0)->nodeValue;

            $st[]=$xmlConn;
        }
```